# Differentiate $\sqrt{\frac{1 +\sin x}{1 -\sin x}}$

Tags: derivatives, trigonometry

I have tried a lot of ways to solve this question but I am unable to get the answer as same as my textbook.

The text book answer is as follow: $$\frac{1}{2}\sec^2\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{{x}}{2}\right)$$

The steps which I took is as follows:

$$\sqrt{\frac{1+ \sin x}{1-\sin x}\cdot \frac{1+\sin x}{1+\sin x}}$$

Then Secondly

$$\sqrt{\frac{\left(1+\sin x\right)^2}{1-\sin^2 x}}$$

Then I got

$$\dfrac{1+\sin x}{\cos x}$$

When I differentiated this I got the following

$$\frac{\cos ^2\left(x\right)+\sin \left(x\right)\left(1+\sin \left(x\right)\right)}{\cos ^2\left(x\right)}$$

Can Anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

I also know that $$\sec^2\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{{x}}{2}\right)=\frac{2}{\left(\cos  \frac{x}{2}-\sin\frac{x}{2}\right)^2}$$

Thank you for the help!

Comment: How did you get$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\frac{1+\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}=\frac{1+\sin(x)}{\cos^2(x)}$$? Also you want to take care of the square root. $\frac{1+\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$ can be negative, but the original square root cannot.

Comment: opps its a mistake its $\frac{\cos ^2\left(x\right)+\sin \left(x\right)\left(1+\sin \left(x\right)\right)}{\cos ^2\left(x\right)}$

Using mathjax is hard for me that is why..Sorry!

Comment: You can simplify your answer a bit using $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$. Regardless, I don't think you've done anything wrong: Your book's answer and yours are equivalent, up to use of the half-angle identities.(Try multiplying both top and bottom of your last expression by $(\cos(x/2)+\sin(x/2))^2$.)

Comment: Dude U gave me the perfect answer Thanks!! :))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why make things complicated if there is a easy way? By the half-angle formulae we obtain

$$\sqrt{\frac{1-\sin(x)}{1+\sin(x)}}=\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos\left(x+\frac\pi2\right)}{1+\cos\left(x+\frac\pi2\right)}}=\tan\left(\frac x2-\frac\pi4\right)$$

And I suppose you can differentiate the tangent function ;)

---

As pointed out by *Simply Beautiful Art* and *mathcounterexamples.net* by using the half-angle formula we ran into serious issus concerning the sign.

Comment: How do we differentiate the tanget function..I really suck at trignometry..

Comment: It would appear the textbook answer cares not for the sign of the square root :/

Comment: @Utkarsh Do you know the quotient rule and at least how to differentiate $\sin$ and $\cos$?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Did I made a mistake? o.O

Comment: Clearly $\tan$ can be negative, though the other side cannot, a common thing that gets dropped in the half angle formulae.

Comment: You don't always have $\sqrt{x^2} = x$, i.e. $\sqrt{(-2)^2} \neq -2$.

Comment: Yep I know how to quotient rule and to differentiate sin and cos

Comment: @Utkarsh then what's the derivative of $\sin(x)/\cos(x)$?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt If I am not mistake, simply differentiating by the chain rule would not take care of this either, or would it?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Its $\sec ^2\left(x\right)$

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt won't rationalizing work?

Comment: It would, as differentiating $\sqrt x$ gives $\frac1{2\sqrt x}$, which preserves the sign.

Comment: @Utkarsh Precisely! Now, take care of the different argument and apply the chain rule.

Comment: yeah textbook answer is weird derivative of given function isn't always non negative https://www.desmos.com/calculator/nxd2uanogw

Comment: @Utkarsh Yes it is $\sec^2(x)$. Yes, rationalizing would also work, as you've done in your post with the update. Take note however that both answers are technically wrong, as they fail to account for the fact that $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$, not $x$.

Comment: Okay. Got it so is there any way of getting the right answer? If so what is it? I have been trying almost everything...

Comment: :p as for fixing the answer, it suffices to deduce when to use $\tan\left(\frac x2-\frac\pi4\right)$ or $-\tan\left(\frac x2-\frac\pi4\right)$ and differentiate appropriately.

Answer (score 4):

Logarithmic differentiation makes things easier
$$y=\sqrt{\dfrac{1 +\sin (x)}{1 -\sin (x)}}\implies \log(y)=\frac 12 \left(\log(1+\sin(x)) -\log(1-\sin(x))\right)$$
$$\frac {y'}{y}=\frac 12 \left(\frac{\cos(x)}{1+\sin(x) }+\frac{\cos(x)}{1-\sin(x) }\right)$$ Simplify as much as you can and, when finished, use
$$y'=y\times \frac {y'}{y}$$

Comment: +1. Indeed, $\frac{y'}{y}=\frac{1}{\cos x}$ and $y'=\frac{y}{\cos x}=\frac{1}{1-\sin x}$ is a lot shorter and simpler than direct calculation.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, using the product rule:
$$\begin{align}\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{1 +\sin x}{1 -\sin x}}\right)'
&=(\sqrt{1+\sin x})'\cdot (1-\sin x)^{-1/2}+\sqrt{1+\sin x}\cdot ((1-\sin x)^{-1/2})'=\\
&=\frac{\cos x}{2\sqrt{1+\sin x}}\cdot \frac1{\sqrt{1-\sin x}}+\sqrt{1+\sin x}\cdot \frac{\cos x}{2(1-\sin x)\sqrt{1-\sin x}}=\\
&=\frac{\cos x}{2\sqrt{\cos ^2x}}+\frac{\cos x\sqrt{(1+\sin x)^2}}{2(1-\sin x)\sqrt{1-\sin ^2x}}=\\
&=\frac12+\frac{1+\sin x}{2(1-\sin x)}=\\
&=\frac1{1-\sin x}=\cdots =\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\sec^2\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{{x}}{2}\right)\end{align}$$
Can you show the equality of the last two expressions using what you stated you know?

Answer (see the hidden area):

> $$\frac1{1-\sin x}=\frac{1}{\sin^2x+\cos^2x-2\sin \frac{x}{2}\cos \frac{x}{2}}=\frac{1}{(\sin \frac x2-\cos \frac x2)^2}=\\=\frac{1}{2(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sin \frac x2-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cos \frac x2)^2}=\frac{1}{2\cos^2(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac x2)}=\frac12\sec^2(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac x2).$$

Answer (score 1):

What if $1\pm\sin x=0?$

Otherwise
$$\sqrt{\dfrac{1+\sin x}{1-\sin x}}=\sqrt{\left(\dfrac{1+\tan\dfrac x2}{1-\tan\dfrac x2}\right)^2}=\left|\tan\left(\dfrac\pi4+\dfrac x2\right)\right|$$ using
https://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/algebra/WeierstrassSubstitution.shtml

Now $\tan\left(\dfrac\pi4+\dfrac x2\right)$ will be $>0$ if $1-\tan^2\dfrac x2>0\iff-1<\tan\dfrac x2<1$

Answer (score 0):

The textbook answer may not be quite right.
For x in range $[0, 2\pi],\text{ only } [0, {\pi \over 2}], [{3\pi \over 2},2\pi]$ work.

This is a revised derivative, to handle the full range.

$$\left(\sqrt{{1+\sin(x) \over 1-\sin(x)}} \right)' = {sign(\cos(x))\over 2} \sec^2({\pi \over 4} + {x \over 2})$$

Of course, chain rule result works too, but a bit messy.
After some simplification, this is what I have.
Note: derivative have the sign of $\cos(x)$, as expected.
$$\left(\sqrt{{1+\sin(x) \over 1-\sin(x)}} \right)'
= {\cos(x) \over (1-\sin(x))^2 \sqrt{{1+sin(x) \over 1-sin(x)}}}$$